# Exponential Numbers conversion in C++, MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, cstring

I am very new to MFC and now I want to convert Exponential Numbers "4.246E+3" into 4246.

Input is in string and output I want to get it in int.

Please let me know if we have any way(API) to get it in MFC, C++.

Thanks
MAP

Comment: MFC is primarily a Windows GUI Programming Library, so I wouldn't expect it to contain such a conversion function. You might to check the C++ reference [cstdlib atof](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/) This contains information about exponent E/e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code will work fine to solve your problem...

```
#include<sstream>

string str = "4.246e+3";
stringstream ss;
double number;
ss<<str;
ss>>number;
```

Comment: This is a C++-ish solution; you can construct the `stringstream` from the string directly, though.  (`stringstream ss(str);`)

Comment: Yes I know that...was trying to make my answer more explanatory..thanks for pointing out that...

Comment: I guess correct line is ss>>number; instead of str>>number;

Comment: I'd even write `std::stringstream ss("4.246e+3")`. No need to create all kind of named temporaries.

Answer (score -1):

You can the standard library function which allows for `str` to be in scientific notation.

```
int stoi (const string&  str, size_t* idx = 0, int base = 10);
```

If you supply `idx` and it comes back `nullptr` then `str` was a pure number, if not then it returns the address of the first invalid character in `str`.

It's better to use the standard C++ library functions rather than MFC whenever possible to assist in any future porting out of MFC.

Comment: This is my code std::string input = "4.246e+3";
 std::string::size_type sz;
 int output = stoi(input, NULL, 0);

Comment: Oh - you removed the brackets :).  I was in doubt; but you advise using a C-stdlib function, while the C++ stl stream extractor is way more useful. in this context.

Comment: @xtofl: `std::stoi` isn't C, as you could deduce from its first argument.

Comment: @Bathsheba: `std::stoi` parses the same format as `std::strtol`, which is to say a simple sequence of digits. The example has an `e+` in the middle.

Comment: @MSalters: You're right; my bad - probably `stof` is better to parse a float, though :)  I confused it with `atoi` and friends.